# Unit test a subscription in ngOnInit not working

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have subsriber to an observable on ngOnInit and now I am trying to write test for this which doesn't seems working.

Here is my class which I am trying to test

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.updates$.pipe(takeUntil(unsusbribe$))
   .subscribe(update => {
     this.feeds = update;
  })
}
```

Here is my unit test for this

```
it('should set feeds when an update is sent', fakeAsync(() => {
const update = 'fakeUpdate';
component.ngOnInit();
  const serviceSpy = spyOn(myService, 'updates$').and.returnValue(timer(500).pipe(mapTo(update)))
tick(500);
expect(serviceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
}))
```

This test fails with error `Expected spy updates$ to have been called.`

Can anyone please help me figuring out the issue here.

Comment: Where is ngOnInit being called in your test? If it isn't called, why would your spy be called?

Comment: @JBNizet I just updated question... its been called on ngOnInit(). So I have called component.ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to use spy service. Please try this one.

```
  it('should set feeds when an update is sent', fakeAsync(() => {
    const update = 'fakeUpdate';
    const serviceSpy = spyOn(myService, 'updates$');
    serviceSpy.and.returnValue(timer(500).pipe(mapTo(update)))
    tick(500);
    expect(serviceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  }))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this still seems not working.